# Are there any integers which could never be a Godel Number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a system where a number such as $121$ can be encoded into a Godel number, are there any integers which could never be the result?

As I understand it, we line up the primes and raise these to the digit we wish to encode and then multiply these together to find the Godel encodeing of number.

So $121$ is encoded as follows:

$2^1 * 3^2 * 5^1 \implies 2 * 9 *5 = 90$

So $90$ is the Godel number for $121$.

I am interested to know what integers (if any) could never be a Godel number.
Further more, I would like to know if this set of numbers has a name and if they have anything else in common or are useful for anything.

Comment: There are many [Gödel numbering(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering): in general, the encoding rule has the property that from the code we can retrieve the formula but not every number will be a code.

Comment: See the post [What does a Godel sentence actually look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472769/what-does-a-godel-sentence-actually-look-like) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483113/understanding-g%c3%b6dels-1931-paper-primitive-recursive-functions-frx-and-n) for some "exercises" in encoding.

Comment: Because the first digit cannot be zero, Godel numbers are always even, never odd.

Comment: There are Gödel numberings such that any natural number is a Gödel number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any odd integer (unless leading zeros are allowed) and any integer for which there is at least one prime dividing it ten or more times could never be a Godel number.

In particular, $2^{10}=1024$ cannot be a Godel number, because only digits $0$ to $9$ are allowed.

In case of a negative integer $n$, one should assume that the Godel number of $n$ is just $-m$, where $m$ is the Godel number of $-n$, so that the question still makes sense for negative integers.